# Assuming working with Linux

Tags: linux, twitter-bootstrap

I am a beginner in web development and I am going to start working on a project at my new job in a month.

I want to be prepared for the following that are mentioned below for my new job.

Frameworks:
- Bootstrap
- Laravel
- Etc.

For some reason I cannot understand wether every install page of a framework assumes that the installer uses Linux?

For example the bootstrap install page:

> Install with Bower

```
$ bower install bootstrap
```

> Install with npm

```
$ npm install bootstrap
```

> Install with Composer

```
$ composer require twbs/bootstrap
```

Why do major frameworks automatically make that assumption?
And even more important, where do I start learning?

Best regards,
Bart

Comment: Why is that assuming only to work on Linux? Node.js (where npm is the package manager for) works also on Windows, and bower can be installed from npm. So for the first two, there is nothing assuming you need Linux (and composer can also be installed on Windows!). But you're right somehow: Linux (or Unix-like) operating systems are the defacto-standard on the web (as most webservers run on some kind of Linux OS), so you should always have an eye on the basics of Linux - this will help you on nearly every programming related job in the future. I wish you good luck with your first project!

Comment: Thank you for your response!
So would you advice to dual install on my PC and start (web) developing on Linux? Or is it just to learn the basics, because I'm familiar with that :)

Comment: You don't need Linux for web development, but it makes many things easier. You could for example try Vagrant for using a virtual machine with Linux, but you still can edit your source files in an editor of your choice on Windows with that. Or simply start with on Windows by installing Node.js an some tutorials. You really don't need Linux knowledge or machines before starting web development!

Answer (score 1):

They don't assume Linux. They assume some Unix-like environment which has a bourne shell. That could be Linux, OSX, Solaris, and lots of other things. (could be even cygwin on Windows) And that's mostly because having a nice development environment in Windows is hard. Also, you're likely going to deploy the service on something different than a Windows host.

Comment: What do you advice I start developing in then? I'm open for all suggestions, but I just need to know where to start. There are 234234x solutions. And my problem is that I have difficulties picking one...

Comment: As in what system? If you're on Windows, these days it's probably the easiest to start with Ubunt inside a VM (virtualbox or vmware player)

Answer (score 1):

Linux is just a better overall environment for development in general. Assuming you are using Windows, the next best step is to either install a **Cygwin** terminal such that you have access to a **bourne** shell terminal, which is an essential part of your toolkit as a programmer, or set up either a virtual machine (VM) which runs a Linux distribution or dual boot Linux with Windows.

I recommend the latter if you are planning to delve deeper into this field as a VM obviously has limitations, and not just in the performance sense. But since you are just starting out with Linux, a Cygwin terminal might be a better choice to get used to the bourne shell.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've been using PuTTY on my last job for the last 1.5 years. I guess I can see Cygwin as a similar program?

Comment: I am not familiar with Putty but if you can execute specific *nix commands like 'apt-get' as for a Debian based system then that should be a perfect alternative. Otherwise just get yourself a unix based virtual box and you should be good to go! Best of luck in your new job!

Comment: PuTTY just is a terminal emulator (serial/ ssh) for Windows-- you still need a *nix box along with it.  When I'm Ina Windows environment I always install Cygwin, as well as a few GNU commands that work in the Windows cmd shell (Since Cygwin still has some trouble interoperating with Windows style pathnames).

Answer (score 0):

Another factor is that open source is just so much easier (and cheaper for developers) on *nixen.  If you have the money, and play only in the Windows world, you can go 100% Microsoft and have some decent tools. It's ok if your company has big budget and you don't mind being constrained with what Microsoft offers.

If you watch what MS is doing in their OS and development tools space, you'll see that they're working very hard to correct at least the **assumptions** made above.

Still, it's more expensive and more frustrating developing open source in Windows.

Note: I've worked in both worlds and find that a *nix environment provides me the most enjoyment and flexibility, though you can be fairly productive **at the task at hand** stuck in a good, modern MS IDE.